# Angularjs: ngRepeat and directive

Tags: angularjs, directive

I am trying to make some reusable countdown widgets. Works well with a static content, but when i'm trying to add them on the fly, my directive doesn't understand the variables inside the ngRepeat.

Markups:

```
<div ng-repeat="cdn in countdowns" class="countdown" countdown-end="{{cdn}}">
  <p ng-hide="over">{{days}} jours {{hours}} heures {{minutes}} min {{seconds}} sec</p>
  <p ng-show="over">Done</p>
</div>
```

Directive:

```
...
link: function(scope, elm, attrs) {
  scope.days = '1';
  ...
}
...
```

http://jsfiddle.net/hFGb7/14/

Thanks for the replies.

Comment: Not an answer but an observation: scope should be $scope

Comment: Hmm in the doc its scope for the link function

Comment: It is what you call it! The convention is that the built-in functions and variables start with $.

Comment: in fact, it makes more sense to call it scope instead of $scope. When you use $scope is when you're using dependency injection - when Angular is going to look up the dependency based on the variable name.

Comment: http://angulartutorial.blogspot.in/2014/04/angular-ng-repeat-in-directive.html

Comment: @NickLewis the scope variable is just a variable containing the scope being passed to the link function, he could name it "apples" if he wanted. It's not an actual reference to $scope. Might want to check out: https://egghead.io/lessons/angularjs-scope-vs-scope

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that the interpolation is not run by the time link function is called. So the value of `{{cdn}}` is not available. There are couple of ways of handling this:

1. You can use `cdn` directly in the link function since it is available on the scope. But this will make the directive dependent on the presence of `cdn` in the scope.
2. The recommended way to get the value of attributes that use interpolation is to use $observe. Check this: http://jsfiddle.net/hFGb7/28/