# Using AngularJS directives when scope is not loaded yet

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying to implement a simple directive based on the jQuery timeago plugin.  Here is the code for the directive (well, as far as I've gotten so far)

```
<small timeago milliseconds="{{conversation.timestamp}}"></small>
```

I am trying to use the timestamp (in milliseconds), and let angularJs bind the timeago() function like this..

```
App.Directives.directive('timeago', function() {

    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        replace: false,
        scope: false,
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {

            scope.$watch('ready', function () {

                var x = attrs['milliseconds'];

                alert(x);

                $(element).timeago();

            });
        },
    };

});
```

It works just fine when I manually set the value of milliseconds, but it seems the $scope hasn't done it's thing yet... I'm sure this is something simple, I just don't know the right words to google it.

Comment: Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13526584/angularjs-ngrepeat-and-directive/13528336#13528336 . You need to use attrs.$observe instead of scope.$watch

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not sure that `scope.$watch` does what you are expecting it to do; `scope.$watch` takes as its first argument an expression to evaluate on the current scope; when that expression returns a new value, it will call the second argument, a function, with the new value. Thus,

```
scope.$watch('ready', function() {...});
```

is basically the same as saying

> Call this function every time `scope.ready` changes.

which is obviously not what you want.

---

On to your functionality--there are a few ways you might go about implementing something like this. The first is a simple filter:

```javascript
app.filter('timeago', function() {
  return function(time) {
    if(time) return jQuery.timeago(time);
    else return "";
  };
});
```

```html
<p>The timestapm was {{conversation.timestamp|timeago}} ago.</p>
```

In this case, however, the returned string would automatically refresh any time a digest cycle is run on the scope.

To only process the timestamp exactly once, you might use a directive like the following:

```javascript
app.directive('timeago', function($timeout) {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    link: function(scope, elem, attrs) {
      scope.$watch(attrs.timeago, function(value) {                
        if(value) elem.text(jQuery.timeago(value));
      });
    }
  };
});
```

```html
<p>The timestamp was <span timeago="conversation.timestamp"></span> ago.</p>
```

Here is a version that re-runs a digest cycle every 15 seconds, to automatically update the timestamp every so often:

```javascript
app.directive('timeago', function($timeout) {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    link: function(scope, elem, attrs) {
      var updateTime = function() {
        if (attrs.timeagoAutoupdate) {
          var time = scope.$eval(attrs.timeagoAutoupdate);
          elem.text(jQuery.timeago(time));
          $timeout(updateTime, 15000);
        }
      };
      scope.$watch(attrs.timeago, updateTime);
    }
  };
});
```

```html
<p>The timestamp was <span timeago="conversation.timestamp"></span> ago.</p>
```

[Here is a jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BinaryMuse/un8ch/) that demonstrates all three examples. Do note that the only reason the third example (with the filter) is automatically updating every minute is becaues the second example (the `timeagoAutoupdate` directive) is calling `scope.$eval`.